# Cython + ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes, cython, pysdl2

We are currently using `Cython` to make bindings to some networking and DB libraries. We want also use `SDL`, but `PySDL2` uses `ctypes` for binding. While `Cython` is whole interpreter, `ctypes` is just library. But, `Cython` and `ctypes` are most often portrayed as alternatives to each other. Thus I am totally unsure if they are compatible.

So, question: it is possible to use `Cython` and `ctypes` together in one project?

Comment: Yes, they don't interfere. Cython compiles to a normal python module, so you can use it with any library.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a brief summary of how  both tools work:

ctypes is a very pythonic wrapper over a library called `cffi`, which is able to load shared libraries (`.so` or `.dll` files), and call them, without first compiling any code to wrap the functions defined in those libraries.  You do have to tell ctypes about the functions it'll call, so that it can convert from the python types (`int`, `str`, and so on) to the abi expressed in the shared lib (`uint32_t`, `char *`, and so on).

Cython is a 'sort of python' to C translator.  The generated C code can be compiled and the result is a special sort of shared library (`.so` or `.dll` again) which has all the right functions to be a Python C extension.  Cython is very smart, based on the type annotations in the input, it knows whether to emit code that directly calls C functions (when you use `cdef`) or calls regular python objects by way of the `PyObject_Call` C api.

Since you can (more or less) freely mix C and python in Cython sources, you should have no difficulty using PySDL2 in your Cython library, just invoking it as though it were regular python, import it, call it, everything should "just work".

That said, You might benefit from including `libsdl` declarations in your code, directly, if you end up calling out to SDL from tight inner loops, to avoid the overhead of converting from the low level C types to python types, just to have `ctypes` convert them back again.  You could probably put that off until your application has grown a bit and you notice some performance bottlenecks.